# Find all primes such that $a^2+b^2=9ab-13$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> Let $a,b$ be primes. Find all primes such that $a^2+b^2=9ab-13$.

Whatever I've done is from parity checking. But I can't proceed with the case when both $a,b$ are odd primes. 
I tried with some modulo-chasing but couldn't complete.

Comment: $a = 2$ and $b = 17$ appears to work, and so does $a=17$ and $b = 151$

Comment: The cases where one of the primes is even can be found out by the roots of the equation: $2^2+b^2=9 \cdot 2 \cdot b -13=0$. But what about the case when both $a,b$ are odd? Any idea?

Comment: Another solution: $a=310957991$ with $b=34988311$

Comment: @vrugtehagel Your example has $a^2 + b^2 = 9ab - 7$.

Comment: I think it's true that all solutions with odd primes have $ab = 3$ mod $4$. Not sure how useful that is.

Comment: So, mathbg, where did you get the problem?

Comment: @WillJagy I got this from one of my friends, who got from AoPS (Art of Problem Solving)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unlikely that this can be finished... ALL integer solutions are in two families, related by the mapping
$$ (x,y) \mapsto (9x-y, x)  $$
beginning with two "seeds,"
$$ (1,2), \; \; (7,1) , \;\; ( 62,7), \;\;  ( 551, 62), \;\;  $$
$$ (2,1), \; \; (17,2) , \;\; ( 151,17), \;\; ( 1342, 151), \;\;  (11927, 1342), \;\; $$
it suffices to take $x,y > 0,$ as we cannot have a solution with $xy \leq 0$

For each orbits, we have separate linear recurrences ( by Cayley-Hamilton),
$$ x_{n+2} = 9 x_{n+1} - x_n,  $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 9 y_{n+1} - y_n.  $$
$$ 2p, \; 17p, \; 151p, \; 1342, \; 11927p, \;  106001, \; 942082, \; 8372737p, \;74412551, \; 661340222, \; 5877649447p, \; 52237504801, \; 464259893762, \; 4126101539057,  $$
Here we see the consecutive primes $17, 151$ which is probably the largest answer.
$$ 1, \; 7p, \; 62, \; 551, \; 4897, \;  43522, \; 386801, \; 3437687, \;  30552382, \; 271533751, \; 2413251377, \; 21447728642, \; 190616306401, \; 1694099028967,  $$

===============================

```
1
2   Prime  ! 
17   Prime  ! 
151   Prime  ! 
1342
11927   Prime  ! 
106001
942082
8372737   Prime  ! 
74412551
661340222
5877649447   Prime  ! 
52237504801
464259893762
4126101539057
36670653957751
325909784080702
2896517402768567
25742746840836401
228788204164759042
2033351090641994977
18071371611613195751
160608993413876766782
1427409569113277705287
12686077128605622580801
112747284588337325521922
1002039484166430307116497
8905608072909535438526551
79148433172019388639622462
703430290475264962318075607   Prime  ! 
6251724181105365272223058001
55562087339473022487689446402
493807061874151837116981959617
4388701469527893511565148190151
39004506163876889766969351751742
346651854005364114391159017575527
3080862179884400139753461806428001
27381107764954237143389997240276482
243349107704703734150756513356060337
2162760861577379370213418622964266551
19221498646491710597770011093322338622
```

================================

```
1
7   Prime  ! 
62
551
4897
43522
386801
3437687
30552382
271533751
2413251377
21447728642
190616306401
1694099028967
15056274954302
133812375559751
1189255105083457
10569483570191362
93936097026638801
834855389669557847   Prime  ! 
7419762409999381822
65943006300324878551
586067294292924525137
5208662642335995847682
46291896486731038104001   Prime  ! 
411418405738243347088327
3656473755157459085690942
32496845390678888424130151
288815134760952536731480417
2566839367457893942159193602
22812739172360092942701262001
202747813183782942542152164407
1801917579481686389936668217662
16014510402151394566887861794551
142328676039880864712054087933297
1264943573956776387841598929605122
11242163489571106625862336278512801
99914527832183183244919427577010087
887988587000077542578412511914577982
7891982755168514699960793179654191751
70139856209516554757068726104973147777
```

================================

Comment: Ah, this makes me believe it can't be solved. Algorithm on primes that follow a recurrence can't be found, are all.

Answer (score 2):

**Not a complete answer**, just a few restrictions...

**Proposition 1.** For any prime $p>3 \Rightarrow 3 \mid p^2-1$ (from [LFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)) and $8 \mid p^2-1$ (from $(2k+1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$). **As a result $24 \mid p^2-1$.**

For $a>3,b>3 \Rightarrow 24 \mid a^2-1$, $24 \mid b^2-1$
and $$24 \mid a^2 + b^2 -2=9ab-15$$
or 
$$8 \mid 3ab-5 \tag{1}$$
But, any prime $p>3$ is of the $p=4k+1$ or $p=4k+3$ form. None of $a,b$ can be of the same form at the same time:

- $a=4k_a+1,b=4k_b+1 \Rightarrow 3ab-5=3(4k_a+1)(4k_b+1)-5=12Q-2$ is not divisible by 4 and thus not divisible by 8.
- $a=4k_a+3,b=4k_b+3 \Rightarrow 3ab-5=3(4k_a+3)(4k_b+3)-5=12Q-22$ is not divisible by 4 and thus not divisible by 8.

As a result, either
$$a=4k_a+1,b=4k_b+3 \color{red}{\text{ or }} a=4k_a+3,b=4k_b+1 \tag{2}$$
Going further:
$$3ab-5=3(4k_a+1)(4k_b+3)-5=3(16k_ak_b+12k_a+4k_b)+4$$
reveals that both $k_a,k_b$ **can't be odd or even at the same time**.

We can also assume $a\leq b$ and from $a^2+b^2-9ab=-13<0$, by checking $x^2-9x+1<0$ where $x=\frac{b}{a}$, [we have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-9x%2B1)
$$a\leq b < 9a \tag{3}$$

Comment: It's awesome. I liked your restrictions.