# Finding all primes $p,q$ with $p^2+q^2=9pq-13$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, vieta-jumping

The last month I was trying to solve a problem of a magazine, and I found the following equation $$p^2+q^2=9pq-13,$$
Where $p$ and $q$ are primes. We need to get solutions when $p$ and $q$ are odd, because if any of them is even, the only solution that works is $(2,17)$. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

I analyzed the discriminant of the quadratic equation and we need to find solutions of $77q^2-52=k^2$, this is a variation of Pell's equations.

Comment: what kind of magazine were u reading wtf

Comment: @SakethMalyala Math Magazine

Comment: "Reader's Diophantine Equation Digest"

Comment: see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279581/find-all-primes-such-that-a2b2-9ab-13

Answer (score 5):

This answer will find all integer answers. Don't know if there is an easy way to find prime answers.

Multiplying by $4$ we get $4p^2-36pq+4q^2=-52$ or $(2p-9q)^2-77q^2=-52$.

Now, if there is a solution to $x^2-77y^2=-52$, with $x,y>0$ then we have that $x,y$ must have the same parity, and we take.

$$\begin{align}x_1+y_1\sqrt{77}&=(x+y\sqrt{77})\left(\frac{9}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{77}\right)\\
&=\frac{9x-77y}{2}+\frac{9y-x}{2}\sqrt{77}
\end{align}$$

If $x$ is the smallest positive integer solution, then we have that:

$$\left|\frac{9x-77y}{2}\right|\geq x$$

So either $x\geq 11y$ or $7y\geq x$. Which means that either $-52=x^2-77y^2\geq 44y^2$ which isn't possible, or $-52=x^2-77y^2\leq -28y^2,$ so the only possible value for $y$ is $y=1$, and this gives $x=5.$

So there are infinitely many solutions, all of the form $$X+Y\sqrt{77}=(5+\sqrt{77})\left(\frac{9}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{77}\right)^k$$

Then $q=Y, p=\frac{X+9Y}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, missed that it was looking for all prime answers. Will add comment at top.

Comment: The factor $\frac{9}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{77}}{2}$ is because is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{77}]$?